# Applying a windowing function to a Dart stream

Tags: dart, stream, dart-async

I am pretty new to Dart, and still wrapping my head around streams. Specifically I am having some difficulty with finding the proper way of making a function that takes a window of N elements from a stream, applies a function to it and restreams the results.

To clarify what I mean, I include an example that I implemented myself which led me to this question. The code takes a byte stream from a file and converts 4 byte chunks to an integer stream. By using an `await for` I was able to accomplish what I wanted but I am looking for a more idiomatic stream based function that accomplishes the same thing, more succinctly.

```
Stream<int> loadData(String path) async* {
  final f = File(path);
  final byteStream = f.openRead();
  var buffer = Uint8List(8);
  var i = 0;
  
  // This is where I would like to use a windowing function
  await for(var bs in byteStream) {
    for(var b in bs) {
      buffer[i++] = b;
      if(i == 8)  {
        var bytes = new ByteData.view(buffer.buffer);
        yield bytes.getUint16(0);
        i = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [bufferCount](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BufferExtensions/bufferCount.html) method from [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package.

> Buffers a number of values from the source Stream by count then emits the buffer and clears it, and starts a new buffer ...

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

main() {
  var bytes = Uint8List.fromList([255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]);
  Stream<int>.fromIterable(bytes)
      .bufferCount(4)
      .map((bytes) => Uint8List.fromList(bytes).buffer)
      .map((buffer) => ByteData.view(buffer).getInt32(0, Endian.little))
      .listen(print); // prints 255 256 257 258
}
```

It is worth noting that this particular task can be performed much easier:

```dart
    bytes.buffer.asInt32List();
```

Comment: Ah clever, yeah I was looking for a generic solution that would window, hopefully something within the standard library of dart but I guess rxdart's bufferCount is the closest thing to a windowing function. Thanks also for the added tip on `asInt32List`, cheers!